# Understanding infinite products convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, infinite-product, entire-functions

I am reading about a convergence problem with infinite products and I am told:

> Any finite sequence $\{c_{n}\}$ in the complex plane has an associated polynomial p(z) that has zeroes precisely at the points of that sequence, $p(z)=\,\prod _{n}(z-c_{n})$.
>
> Also, any polynomial function p(z) in the complex plane has a factorization  $\,p(z)=a\prod _{n}(z-c_{n})$, where a is a non-zero constant and $c_{n}$ are the zeroes of p.

It then says that the infinite product does not converge:

> When one considers the product $\,\prod _{n}(z-c_{n})$ when the sequence $\{c_{n}\}$ is not finite then it can never define an *entire* function, because the infinite product does not converge.

It is somewhat unclear to me why it does not converge, but in any case, it then goes on to state that:

> A necessary condition for convergence of the infinite product in question is that each factor $(z-c_{n})$ must approach 1 as $n\to \infty$

This last part flew right over my head. Why is it necessary for $(z-c_{n})$ to approach 1? There's no explanation provided. I must be lacking some fundamental knowledge so can someone explain to me in *Layman's Terms* why this rule holds true, or perhaps show a proof that might help me understand?

Comment: This is similar to the term test for an infinite series.  If the series $\sum_{n \geqslant 1}a_n$ converges then it is necessary for $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ since the general term is the difference between two partial sums converging to the same value.   An infinite series is a sequence of partial sums,  an infinite product is a sequence of partial products. So if the infinite product converges then the general term, as a ratio of partial products converging to the same value, must converge to $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  the infinite product is convergent, i.e., $P_n = \prod_{k=1}^n(z - c_k) \to P$ as $n \to \infty$, then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (z- c_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{P_n}{P_{n-1}} = \frac{\lim_{n \to \infty}P_n}{\lim_{n \to \infty}P_{n-1}} =1$$